# How to overlap views?

Tags: android

I am making a calendar. Each day is a textview with a number denoting the day of the month.

I'd like to overlay another view which signals that there is an event on that date. See below image or think about how the google calendar app looks. How do I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to make the two textview inside a Relative Layout or a Frame Layout. You can look at [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a TableLayout to store the TextViews in rows and colums.

A possible way of marking a special day would be changing the background resource of the specific cell with one that has a marking on it, that does not overlap with the number.

If you want more fancy stuff, you could write your custom View subclassing TextView, which handles its onDraw calls and everything else.

As far as I know you can use a RelativeLayout to overlap views.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting left drawable (`android:drawableLeft=""`) to the `TextView`. OR, you can use some transparent background images with indicators drawn in top-left.